# How to write if else statement in single line in C#

Tags: c#

In the below code, I am repeating the same code twice except one change. If there is a way to write the same in single line then it would be great.

The only changes I made is `Obsc` and `zp` based on the `if..else` statement.

```
var zp = __Services.GetValue("Z", Order.Code);
var St="";
if(sp.Label != null)
{
    var Obsc = _Services.GetValue("Z", sp.Label);
    St= string.Format(Obsc, .......,userProfile.DisplayName());
}
else
{
    St = string.Format(zp, ......., userProfile.DisplayName());
}
```

Comment: [?: operator (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

Comment: Using the null coalescing operator, the whole thing in one line: `var St = string.Format(_Services.GetValue("Z", sp.Label ?? Order.Code), ......., userProfile.DisplayName());`

Comment: For future reference: If you have working code that just needs improving, try [codereview.se].

Comment: Why do you call `_Services.GetValue` twice?

Answer (score 0):

The ternary (*) operator, also known as the "conditional operator" is basically a short-hand for "if  then  else " and is written like so:

```
result = condition ? trueValue : falseValue;
```

It is not comparable to an actual `if ... else ...` statement as it is an expression and must provide a value.

See its documentation in the C# language reference for full details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator.

*) So called because it is the only operator that takes 3 arguments. Compare with "binary operator" and "unary operator".

Answer (score 0):

Are you happy with something like this?

```
var code = sp.Label is null
                ? Order.Code
                : sp.Label;

var zpOrObsc = service.GetValue("Z", code); // please use a valid variable name
var st = string.Format(zpOrObsc, ......, userProfile.DisplayName());
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a variable to determine which parameter value you want to call `GetValue` with. You only need to call `GetValue` once and `string.Format` once.

```
var whateverTheSecondParamForGetValueIs = Order.Code;

if (sp.Label != null) {
    whateverTheSecondParamForGetValueIs = sp.Label;
}

var zp = _Services.GetValue("Z", Order.Code);
var St = string.Format(zp, ......., userProfile.DisplayName());
```

No, this isn't a "single line", but I don't see the appeal in that. To me, this is much more readable than any ternary operator.

---

I'm also going to say that these variable names need quite an improvement. They don't convey any meaning.

Comment: I don't think calling `_Services.GetValue` twice is an improvement.

Comment: @NetMage shrug, maybe. I have no idea what the types in play are. Maybe `Order.Code` is expensive, maybe not. But yes, edited to what's probably less expensive.

Answer (score 0):

```
St = string.Format(_Services.GetValue("Z", sp.Label ?? Order.Code), ......., userProfile.DisplayName());
```